# Hibernate filtered collection

Tags: hibernate

I'm searching for a solution (if exist) on my need about an hibernate criteria.

I have 
**ClassA** which have a set of **ClassB** which have a set of **ClassC**.
ClassC have 5 boolean properties calculated by 5 formulas.

What i need is load every class A with only the ClassB that have at least one ClassC with one property true.

for example:

- **A1**

  - **B1**

    - **C1** (1,0,0,0,0)
    - C2 (0,0,0,0,0)
  - B2

    - C3 (0,0,0,0,0)
  - **B3**

    - C4 (0,0,0,0,0)
    - **C5** (0,0,1,0,0)
    - C6 (0,0,0,0,0)

I want to get by Hibernate only the bold signed object, but hibernate will return everything is inside A1 (correctly!!!).

There is a way to tell hibernate to not load everything?

This is what I do

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(ClassA.class, "a");

c.createAlias("a.classBs", "b").setFetchMode("b", FetchMode.SELECT);
c.createAlias("b.classCs", "c").setFetchMode("c", FetchMode.SELECT);

Disjunction or = Restrictions.disjunction();
or.add(Restrictions.eq("c.propOne", Boolean.TRUE));
or.add(Restrictions.eq("c.propTwo", Boolean.TRUE));
or.add(Restrictions.eq("c.propThree", Boolean.TRUE));
or.add(Restrictions.eq("c.propFour", Boolean.TRUE));
or.add(Restrictions.eq("c.propFive", Boolean.TRUE));
c.add(or);  

ret = (List<ClassA>) c .list();
```

P.S. I can't use filter into set mapping because boolean property formulas are too long for manteinance